# Put laravel online

Tags: laravel-5

I've just finished my first laravel project. Now I want to put it online. When I go to one of my domains and put it online with filezilla it works. But that's the wrong domain.

I've a domain with hosting and today I attached another domain here. So if I want to put something on that domain that I just bought today I've to go to:

/Public_html/mydomain.com

But when I put my laravel project in here it doesn't work! Already found a lot of descriptions on google and they are all telling me I've to change the index.php file.

But what should be the path in index.php now>
[image]

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Do you see anything at all? Is PHP executed? Any error messages?

Comment: I just see a white page and my console is telling me: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This is my current path: require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';  $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: Please see my picture.

Comment: Your app lives inside the public folder. You have to either run it through there or change folder structure or edit your htaccess to load from there...

Comment: Oke, but what should my folder structure be than?

Comment: Check this article: https://hellocoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel/

Comment: Making a few assumptions here, but: your vhost is probably set to point to /Public_html/mydomain.com. You need to change it to point to /Public_html/mydomain.com/public